# Tensorflow Slicing/extracting

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
tensor = array([[
    [ 0.1,  0.8],
    [ 0.1,  0.8],
    [ 0.1,  0.8]],

   [[ 0.9,  0.3],
    [ 0.1,  0.8],
    [ 0.9,  0.3]],

   [[ 0.1,  0.8],
    [ 0.1,  0.8],
    [ 0.9,  0.3]]])

selector = array([
    [0, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 0]])


want = array([
    [0.1 0.1 0.8],
    [0.3 0.8 0.3],
    [0.8 0.8 0.9]
    ])
```

Tensor T is NxNxK and selector is NxN. Each element v(i,j) in the selector indicates: grab the v(i,j)-th element from T[i,j].

Is there a way to achieve this is numpy or tensorflow? Thanks!

---- Update
Thanks Alok Singhal for the answer in Numpy. Is there a way to do this if tensor and selector are both tensorflow Tensor?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
>>> i, j = np.ogrid[0:3, 0:3]
>>> i
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])
>>> j
array([[0, 1, 2]])
>>> tensor[i, j, selector]
array([[ 0.1,  0.1,  0.8],
       [ 0.3,  0.8,  0.3],
       [ 0.8,  0.8,  0.9]])
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks

Comment: Actually, is there a way if Tensor and selector are both tf.Variable? tensor[i, j, selector] does not seem to work in this case.